# Oracle insert parallel for empty database

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, insert

I'm using Oracle 11GR2 and I have a problem when I try to insert a lot of rows into a table.
Here is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE ref_bic (
    id_bic              NUMBER(9),
    country_id          NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL,
    bank_code           VARCHAR(5),
    bic_code            VARCHAR(20),
    bank_name           VARCHAR(150)        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_ref_bic PRIMARY KEY (id_bic)
);
```

And here is an example of what I'm inserting :

```
INSERT INTO REF_BIC (country_id, bank_code, bic_code, bank_name) VALUES (123, '123456', '12345', 'SOME BANK NAME');
```

Note that the id_bic is self generated.

Now here is my problem, I have more than 30k rows like this one to insert in my database the first time I'm creating it, and every-time it takes me more than 30 minutes to insert all the datas.

I have heard that I could use PARALLEL and APPEND to insert is faster, and that the only requirement is to use

```
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML;
```

I tried and it don't seem to work

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(REF_BIC) */ INTO REF_BIC (country_id, bank_code, bic_code, bank_name) VALUES (123, '123456', '12345', 'SOME BANK NAME');
```

It is not interpreted, even if I take off the /* */, it's only making me an error.

Now, it seems like the parallel insert need to be from a subquery like

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(REF_BIC) */ INTO REF_BIC SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

But i can't use a subquery since I am creating my database for the first time, it is totally empty.

So here are my questions :

- Does parallel insert work without subquery ?
- And if not, how can I insert quicker my < 30k rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have more than 30k rows like this one to insert in my database

Use a text editor/excel to construct and put all of them in a **single** query joined by `UNION ALL` , I bet it will be much faster ( with or without parallel hint )

```
insert into REF_BIC (country_id, bank_code, bic_code, bank_name) 
select 123, '123456', '12345', 'SOME BANK NAME'   from dual union all
select 124, '123457', '12348', 'SECOND BANK NAME' from dual union all
..
..
```

Comment: This seems to work faster than the current method I am using, thank you. I need to split the < 30k rows in like 6 or 7 times because 30k rows is apparently too big for one insert, but still it is a progress !

Comment: Ok, so I have seperated the < 30k row in groups of 1k, it takes me now 15-20 seconds to insert the whole thing, thank you a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use like types, remove the single quotes around the bank_code and bic_code values.

Just turn you insert statements into an anonymous block. Before the first put the line

```
BEGIN
```

After the last put the lines

```
commit;
end;
```

I had a similar situation with about 12K insert records, after sandwiching it within an anonymous block it finished within seconds.

Comment: I know I should be using like types, but I can't, there is some cases where the bank_code or the bic_code can contain letters.

Comment: Also i tried the anonymous block, 30k is too big and it don't seem to really improve the speed of inserts, sorry :/